# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.content.Context.startActivity(android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I tried to implement a `VoiceRecognitionService` in Android. In my case after the end of the voice record, I need to start an `Intent`. But when I'm attempting to do this I got,

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.content.Context.startActivity(android.content.Intent)' on a null object reference

My class looks like,

```
public class VoiceRecService extends Application implements RecognitionListener {
    /* other methods and contents */

    @Override
public void onEndOfSpeech() {
        double latitude = 31.249351;
        double longitude = 121.45905;

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                .parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr="
                        + latitude + ","
                        + longitude + "&daddr="
                        + 31.186371 + "," + 121.489885));
        notificationIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(notificationIntent);
    }
}
```

How may I start an intent using `startActivity(notificationIntent)`. If it's possible, how may I fix this?

Comment: Where you are using `VoiceRecService ` class in code? and also make sure you have registered `VoiceRecService ` in `Manifest` file

Comment: Are you actually using the `VoiceRecService` class as your `Application`? That is, is it listed as the `name` attribute of the `<application>` element in your manifest? I would guess that it doesn't really need to be an `Application` subclass. You could make it a `Service` class instead, or pass a valid `Context` to any instantiated objects otherwise.

Comment: How may I define it? It's not an activity or a service.

Comment: Then make it a regular class, and pass any instantiated objects a valid `Context` through a constructor or public method.

Comment: @Mike M. - thanks. It works well..

Comment: Cool. Glad you got it.